# How can I get a simulator for an older version of iOS in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I've got the latest Xcode and it has a few simulators - all for ios 13.4.

Can I get it to create one for an older version of ios?

Comment: https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/deva7379ae35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to *Preferences…* ➙ *Components* and you will see the option to install simulators for older versions of iOS.

Then go to *Window* ➙ *Devices and Simulators* ➙ *Simulators* and you will be able to create simulator instances for specific devices running this version of iOS by clicking the add button in the bottom-left corner of the window.